# Adding a script to the page dynamically with jQuery never uses the cached file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to dynamically add a script to my page and it works, but jQuery appends "_=TIMESTAMP" to the URL causing the browser to never use the cache.  With the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("head").append('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see in firebug that the URL requested is:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js?_=1313291978667
```

Does anyone know how to tell jQuery not to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of appending the script tag you can use `getScript` method of jquery to get js script file on the page

Comment: Just as a tip you should use your urls starting with "//ajax.googleapis..." instead of "https://ajax.googleapis...". Because this will cause an error if your page is not accessed through SSL. Note that the url you are getting needs to support this hack (google services does). This will ensure that your page works both on SSL and without it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To answer your original question, you see the timestamp appended because jQuery [by default](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) sets `cache: false` for `script` and `jsonp` calls which appends the timestamp to the URL.

To avoid the timestamp, you can do this:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
  if ( options.dataType == 'script' || originalOptions.dataType == 'script' ) {
      options.cache = true;
  }
});
```

This sets up a global [prefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) for all `$.ajax` calls, including the ones made by jQuery while requesting the `script`.

We inspect the `dataType` to make sure we're not inadvertantly targetting other ajax calls and explicitly set `cache` to `true`. This will avoid the timestamp appending problem.

You can now use your original code and it'll pick it up from cache.

Comment: Excellent answer.  While the other one worked for my particular case, this is a more complete answer.

Comment: This helped me out, thanks. Just for the sake of completeness: that `:` needs to be a `=`.

Comment: @Mrchief where would you put this piece of code?  I've tried to put it in the head, but each script tag is still appending a timestamp afterwards.

Comment: You could place anywhere between downloading jQuery and running your first ajax call. So if you're putting it in head, make sure you put if after jQuery is downloaded. Also, check if any other part of your code is downloading jQuery again. If so, then that jQuery download will wipe out this guy.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `$.ajax` to get the script instead of appending script tag

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js",
  dataType: "script",
  cache: true,//This will decide whether to cache it or no so that it will not add the timestamp along with the request
  success: function(){}//In the success handler you can write your code which uses resources from this js file ensuring the script has loaded successfully before using it
});
```

Comment: I think you meant `true`, not `ture` on the `cache`.

Comment: Your solution was exactly what I needed, but I didn't mark it as answer because I would still like to know if there is a way to fix the original problem.  In this particular case, I just wanted to load the script, but what if I was loading HTML from an ajax request that used script includes?  I would still want that to use the cache.

Answer (score 4):

Here is something that works for me

```
// Backup the jquery ajax cache setting
var jQueryAjaxSettingsCache = jQuery.ajaxSettings.cache;

// Disable the ?_=TIMESTAMP addition
jQuery.ajaxSettings.cache = true;

// Do the cached script inserting ...
$("head").append('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');

// Restore the jquery ajax cache setting
jQuery.ajaxSettings.cache = jQueryAjaxSettingsCache;
```