# jQuery rewriting src attribute on script tag dynamically written onto page (adding timestamp, prevents use of browser cache)

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery's .prepend(), .html(), and .after() functions to write HTML on to my page.  This includes a  tag to a static JavaScript file.

What I've discovered is that something (jQuery, I'm guessing) is rewriting my  tag's src attribute to include a timestamp in the querystring.  This prevents browser caching from being used, which in my case is something I want, because it is a static JavaScript file and if the browser already has the file in cache, I don't want it forced to make another HTTP request.

I'm also doing more traditional JSONP requests, in which this feature is extremely useful--it prevents the browser from using a cached result from a past JSONP request.

Is there a way to disable this "src rewriting feature" **without disabling the timestamps being appended to JSONP requests?**  As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054795/adding-a-script-to-the-page-dynamically-with-jquery-never-uses-the-cached-file), you can setup an ajaxPrefilter which prevents timestamps from being appended, but I think (?) this removes the timestamps from JSONP requests as well.

[Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/jbeall/BkLMx/3/)

Here's the relevant JavaScript code:

```
var scriptTag = "<script type='text/javascript' src='//jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/'></ script>";

var appHost = $('#app-host');

// prepend, html, and after exhibit the same behavior
appHost.prepend(scriptTag);
appHost.html(scriptTag);
appHost.after(scriptTag);
```

Comment: I read that question, but the answer provided sounds like it is going to prevent the timestamp from being appended to the URL for JSONP requests, which won't work for me.  I've got JSONP requests that will break without the timestamp.

Comment: If there's a way to differentiate between a JSONP request and a <script> tag, then I could use an ajaxPrefilter, but since a JSONP request really *is* a <script> tag... I don't know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the following ajaxPrefilter. Basically, I'm inspecting the URL that's being called to ensure that it's one that I want to cache.

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    // We want to make sure that calls to the "JavaScript controllers" via <script>
    // tags are not prevented from using the browser cache.
    if ( options.dataType == 'script' && typeof(options.url) === "string"
        && options.url.toLowerCase().indexOf("js-controllers") > -1) {
        options.cache = true;
    }
});
```

This is working for me, and seems relatively safe.